# How to get the my favorite questions by specified Tag

Tags: support, feature-request

All, How can I get the list of questions from `favorites` by the specified `Tag`.

Let's say it .I want to list all the HTML5 tagged questions in my `favorites`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use advanced search options, specifically

```
infavorites:me
```

combined with the tag you want, like [html5].

That would be: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Ame+%5Bhtml5%5D

(for your posts (instead of favorites), use `user:me`)

Comment: Thanks! It sounds what I need. Where is the advanced search options ? Thanks.

Comment: Just search for something, and they will be shown.

Comment: What is the expression for `add / or` in the http://stackoverflow.com/search. thanks

Comment: @Joe.wang `and` is implicit, `or` wants spelling out. Did you read the help-page too?

Answer (score 2):

There are over 65,000 questions tagged with [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) at the moment. It makes little sense to have *all* of them favorites (you want to know about each edit and new answer on these? Really?).

You can simply go to the tag page and sort according to newness - put that in your browser bookmarks. Sorted.

Comment: Let's say there are thousands of favorite questions in my `favorites` in past a couple of years. and There are only a few of questions tagged with let 's say `ssl`.and I didn't remembered even the rough time when they are marked as `favorite`. You mean I have to review all the questions in thousands of questions page by page until I found the ones tagged with `ssl` ? I can't image it ....thanks.

Comment: I mean that if you are interested in a tag, there is a tag page.

Comment: @Joe.wang And if you want to search in your favorites, that's possible. `infavorites:me` (advanced search option).

Comment: Forgive me I didn't put it clear. I mean select * from questions where the tag like "the specified tag"  and user = "joe.wang" Thanks.